# Yii2 ajax update row status and hide row after status change

Tags: ajax, gridview, row, yii2

I am using Yii2 gridview with custom action button. On click custom button i want to update status of that record and hide that row from gridview.
Also want to show success message.

```php
[  
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'header'=>'Actions',
    'template' => '{confirm}',
    'buttons' => [

        //view button
        'confirm' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a('Confirm', $url, [
                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Confirm Address'),
                'class'=>'btn btn-success',                                  
            ]);
        },
    ],

    'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
        if ($action === 'confirm') {
            return Url::to(['customers/confirmaddress','id'=>$model->id]);

        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `Pjax` at beginning of GridView and configure `dateProvider` to show those value having status other than update Status value on confirm prompt an alert box and make your confirm button to `data-pjax` => true so handle pjax request and update your Pjax -container after ajax request is successfull .. provide some more extra controller code